# Calculation of days between different dates (filter big table)

Tags: r, date, filter, dplyr, days

I am trying to filter a big table from a database so that it works for me in an automated manner.

The current criteria are:
Group by identical name/ID
Filter for specific syntax in the names
Filter for another criteria
and filter/dismiss entries without values (NA in R)

The only two option that are missing are the following
Each ID has a specific date a field for ID and a field for Passage (P0, P1,...)
How can I attach a new column that checks first for the ID, then for Passage and can then take the date of P0 and give me days in betweens as an output?

```
ID1 ID2 Sample_ID   Type    Date    Passage colonies
abc-0001-P0 abc-0001    abc-0001-T  cells   3/22/16 P0  23
abc-0001-P1 abc-0001    abc-0001-T  cells   3/29/16 P1  30
abc-0002-P0 abc-0002    abc-0002-T  cells   4/03/16 P0  5
abc-0002-P1 abc-0002    abc-00021-T cells   5/05/16 P1  18
abc-0002-P2 abc-0002    abc-00021-T cells   5/19/16 P1  27
```

would be great if I get as an output another column for abc-0001 samples as well as dates calculated for the abc-0002 samples referring to the corresponding P0 dates.

as well if there could be a function added that would create a line plot for number of days and colonie_count. -->this is less important than the calculation of the specific dates.

This is my current code:

```
library(readxl)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr

b <- a %>%
    select(ID1, ID2, Sample_ID, Type, Date, Passage, Colonies) %>%
    group_by(ID2) %>%
    filter(str_detect(ID2, 'abc')) %>%
    filter(str_detect(ID1, 'cells')) %>%
    filter(!is.na(Passage))
write.csv(b, file="test.csv")
```

Would be great if you could help me.

Best,

Dennis

---

Adding more examples were I start from and where I want to be:

```
    ID1              ID2    Sample_ID   Type    Date    Passage  colonies
abc-0001-T-P0   abc-0001    abc-0001-T  cells   3/22/16 P0       23
abc-0001-T      abc-0001    abc-0001-T  frozen  3/22/16     
abc-0001-N      abc-0001    abc-0001-N  frozen  3/22/16     
abc-0001-P1     abc-0001    abc-0001-T  cells   3/29/16 P1       30
abc-0002-T-P0   abc-0002    abc-0002-T  frozen  4/03/16     
abc-0002-T-SFT  abc-0002    abc-0002-T  frozen  4/03/16     
abc-0002-N-SFT  abc-0002    abc-0002-N  cells   4/03/16 P0        5
abc-0002-P1     abc-0002    abc-00021-T cells   5/05/16 P1       18
abc-0002-P2     abc-0002    abc-00021-T cells   5/19/16 P1       27
```

I want to get to this:

```
        ID1      ID2    Sample_ID   Type    Date    Passage colonies     days
abc-0001-P0 abc-0001    abc-0001-T  cells   3/22/16 P0      23           0
abc-0001-P1 abc-0001    abc-0001-T  cells   3/29/16 P1      30           7
abc-0002-P0 abc-0002    abc-0002-T  cells   4/03/16 P0      5            0
abc-0002-P1 abc-0002    abc-00021-T cells   5/05/16 P1      18          32
abc-0002-P2 abc-0002    abc-00021-T cells   5/19/16 P1      27          46
```

From this table I would love to generate automatic individual line plots for
days (x-axes) and colonies (y-axes) the name of each plot would be the Sample_ID.

Would be great if this would be possible. thanks!!

Comment: It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you provide a snippet of data we can work from. What is known as [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question. In it's current form `Passage` has no `NA` and `'cells'` will not be found in `ID1`.

Comment: hope this helps. I have more columns in the original table this is why I use the select function but I think this is the essentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could not post it as comment because it was too long
only change that I did as well was converting the date column to a date with

```
a$`Date_Sample_Created?` <- as.Date(a$`Date_Sample_Created?`, format="%Y-%m-%d")
```

Hope this help.

```
structure(list(ID = c("36", "37", "38", "45", "46", "47", "48", 
"57", "59", "121", "131", "132", "134", "206"), Derived_Sample_ID = c("abc-0001-T-p0", 
"abc-0001-T-SFT", "abc-0001-N-SFT", "abc-0002-T-p0", "abc-0002-T-SFT", 
"abc-0002-N-SFT", "abc-0002-T-p1", "abc-0002-T-p2", "abc-0001-T-CPT", 
"abc-0001-T-p1", "abc-0001-T-p2", "abc-0002-T-p3", "abc-0001-T-p3", 
"abc-0002-T-P4"), ID2 = c("abc-0001", "abc-0001", "abc-0001", 
"abc-0002", "abc-0002", "abc-0002", "abc-0002", "abc-0002", "abc-0001", 
"abc-0001", "abc-0001", "abc-0002", "abc-0001", "abc-0002"), 
    Sample_ID = c("abc-0001-T", "abc-0001-T", "abc-0001-N", "abc-0002-T", 
    "abc-0002-T", "abc-0002-N", "abc-0002-T", "abc-0002-T", "abc-0001-T", 
    "abc-0001-T", "abc-0001-T", "abc-0002-T", "abc-0001-T", "abc-0002-T"
    ), `Derived_Sample_Type?` = c("cells", "Frozen tissue", "Frozen tissue", 
    "cells", "Frozen tissue", "Frozen tissue", "cells", "cells", 
    "Frozen tissue", "cells", "cells", "cells", "cells", "cells"
    ), `DNA_concentration?` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `DNA_concentration?__1` = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `Passage_#` = c("P0", 
    NA, NA, "P0", NA, NA, "P1", "P2", NA, "P1", "P2", "P3", "P3", 
    "P4"), `Culture_Plate_Type?` = c("24-well plate", NA, NA, 
    "24-well plate", NA, NA, "24-well plate", "24-well plate", 
    NA, "24-well plate", "24-well plate", "24-well plate", "24-well plate", 
    "6-well plate"), `colonies_#` = c("23", NA, NA, "12", NA, 
    NA, "10", "8", NA, "23", "24", "14", "6", "21"), `Split_Ratio?` = c("NA", 
    NA, NA, "NA", NA, NA, "1:1", "1:1", NA, "1:1", "1:1", "1:2", 
    NA, "NA"), `DNA_concentration?__2` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `DNA_concentration?__3` = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `Date_Sample_Created?` = c("2017-07-26", 
    "2017-07-26", "2017-07-26", "2017-07-28", "2017-07-28", "2017-07-28", 
    "2017-07-31", "2017-08-11", "2017-07-26", "2017-08-21", "2017-08-22", 
    "2017-08-22", "2017-09-01", "2017-09-06"), `Time_Sample_Created?` = c("6:30PM", 
    "5:00PM", "5:00PM", "1:00PM", "11:00AM", "11:00AM", "04:30 PM", 
    "04:00 PM", "5:00PM", "10:00AM", "05:00 PM", "05:00 PM", 
    "01:30 PM", "4:00 PM"), `SOP_used?` = c("Culture of cellss - #5", 
    "Culture of cellss - #5", "Culture of cellss - #5", "Culture of cellss - #5", 
    "Culture of Lung Tumor cellss - #6", "Culture of Lung Tumor cellss - #6", 
    "Culture of cellss - #5", "Culture of cellss - #5", "Culture of cellss - #5", 
    "Culture of cellss - #5", "Culture of cellss - #5", "Culture of cellss - #5", 
    "Culture of cellss - #5", "Culture of cellss - #5"), `Any_changes_to_SOP?` = c("Yes", 
    "No", "No", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "Yes", 
    "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "Yes"), Passage = c("P0", NA, NA, "P0", 
    NA, NA, "P1", "P2", NA, "P1", "P2", "P3", "P3", "P4"), colonies = c("23", 
    NA, NA, "12", NA, NA, "10", "8", NA, "23", "24", "14", "6", 
    "21")), .Names = c("ID", "Derived_Sample_ID", "ID2", "Sample_ID", 
"Derived_Sample_Type?", "DNA_concentration?", "DNA_concentration?__1", 
"Passage_#", "Culture_Plate_Type?", "colonies_#", "Split_Ratio?", 
"DNA_concentration?__2", "DNA_concentration?__3", "Date_Sample_Created?", 
"Time_Sample_Created?", "SOP_used?", "Any_changes_to_SOP?", "Passage", 
"colonies"), row.names = c(NA, -14L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

Thank you so much!!!

Comment: with my conversed dates I can get the difference amnually and the output is # in days so this should work? so the only problem would be to get groups set up for the ID2 and make sure all get substracted from P0 (including P0 as 0) if it would be possible to plot a line plot from all groups this would be amazing.

Comment: adding:     mutate(days = `Date_Sample_Created?` - lag(`Date_Sample_Created?`, by=ID2)) gives me the dates substracted by groups but only one with the next. all need to be substracted from P0 of the same group.

Comment: If I use:     mutate(days = as.Date(`Date_Sample_Created?`) - as.Date(`Date_Sample_Created?`[`Passage_#?` == 'P0'])), by=ID2)) I get an error: Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Column `days` must be length 9 (the group size) or one, not 0

Answer (score 0):

would something lke this do it,

```
tbl %>% group_by(ID2) %>%  filter(!is.na(Passage)) %>% 
    mutate(days = colonies- first(colonies),
           ID1 = paste0(str_extract(ID1, "^abc.\\d+"), '-', Passage))
#> # A tibble: 5 x 8
#> # Groups:   ID2 [2]
#>           ID1      ID2   Sample_ID   Type    Date Passage colonies  days
#>         <chr>   <fctr>      <fctr> <fctr>  <fctr>  <fctr>    <int> <int>
#> 1 abc-0001-P0 abc-0001  abc-0001-T  cells 3/22/16      P0       23     0
#> 2 abc-0001-P1 abc-0001  abc-0001-T  cells 3/29/16      P1       30     7
#> 3 abc-0002-P0 abc-0002  abc-0002-N  cells 4/03/16      P0        5     0
#> 4 abc-0002-P1 abc-0002 abc-00021-T  cells 5/05/16      P1       18    13
#> 5 abc-0002-P1 abc-0002 abc-00021-T  cells 5/19/16      P1       27    22
```

Here's the data, in case others want to give it a go;

```
tbl <- structure(list(ID1 = structure(c(4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 8L, 9L, 5L, 
6L, 7L), .Label = c("abc-0001-N", "abc-0001-P1", "abc-0001-T", 
"abc-0001-T-P0", "abc-0002-N-SFT", "abc-0002-P1", "abc-0002-P2", 
"abc-0002-T-P0", "abc-0002-T-SFT"), class = "factor"), ID2 = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("abc-0001", "abc-0002"
), class = "factor"), Sample_ID = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
4L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("abc-0001-N", "abc-0001-T", "abc-0002-N", 
"abc-0002-T", "abc-00021-T"), class = "factor"), Type = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("cells", "frozen"
), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 5L), .Label = c("3/22/16", "3/29/16", "4/03/16", 
"5/05/16", "5/19/16"), class = "factor"), Passage = structure(c(1L, 
NA, NA, 2L, NA, NA, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("P0", "P1"), class = "factor"), 
    colonies = c(23L, NA, NA, 30L, NA, NA, 5L, 18L, 27L)), .Names = c("ID1", 
"ID2", "Sample_ID", "Type", "Date", "Passage", "colonies"), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Here's code the work on the actual production data,

```
a %>% group_by(ID2) %>%  filter(!is.na(Passage))  %>%
         mutate(colonies_num = as.numeric(colonies), 
                days = colonies_num- first(colonies_num),
                ID = paste0(str_extract(ID, "^abc.\\d+"), '-', Passage)) %>% 
     select(-colonies_num)
#> # A tibble: 9 x 20
#> # Groups:   ID2 [2]
#>      ID Derived_Sample_ID      ID2  Sample_ID `Derived_Sample_Type?`
#>   <chr>             <chr>    <chr>      <chr>                  <chr>
#> 1 NA-P0     abc-0001-T-p0 abc-0001 abc-0001-T                  cells
#> 2 NA-P0     abc-0002-T-p0 abc-0002 abc-0002-T                  cells
#> 3 NA-P1     abc-0002-T-p1 abc-0002 abc-0002-T                  cells
#> ...
```

or better,

```
a %>% group_by(ID2) %>%  filter(!is.na(Passage))  %>%
    mutate(days = as.numeric(colonies)- first(as.numeric(colonies)),
           ID = paste0(str_extract(ID, "^abc.\\d+"), '-', Passage))
```

Comment: thanks already Eric. I got "Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to binary operator." as Error The dates are identified as dates following format="%Y-%m-%d

Comment: that's why we ask you to make a reproducible example, i.e. data that is _identical_ to what you have. Anyway, could share the data with `dput()` or possibly rework the data I've produced to be _identical_ to yours?

Comment: I would guess something like this need to be involved `%>% mutate(Date = lubridate::mdy(Date)) `

Comment: this gave me Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.  the command: a$`Date_Sample_Created?` <- as.Date(a$`Date_Sample_Created?`, format="%Y-%m-%d")  worked for me. at least the column is marked as 'Date'

Comment: that's why we ask you to make a reproducible example, i.e. data that is _identical_ to what you have.

Comment: hope the one below works. first time that I did not find a good example for code here. thats why I have to ask but not used to dput() ... hope that in the answer below everything is answered

Comment: with my conversed dates I can get the difference amnually and the output is # in days so this should work?